# Access 3D world coordinate of specific 2D pixel coordinate in a mapped texture

Tags: python, vector-mapping

I have a 2D image texture mapped to a 3D mesh.

I have a known location in pixel coordinates in the image (eg. 50 pixels right and 27 pixels down from the top left corner).

I want to programmatically position a 3D object 'at' that pixel location.

**How do I access the required information inside of Blender?**

I know blender is looking this information up internally when it looks up what colour to shade a pixel in the viewport or render, but I want to be able to access it from Python inside of blender.

A bit more background - I have image textures that have been through image recognition software. The results are known locations of interest in image space, and I'd like to point a camera at these locations.

An approach I've considered - in the case of a square, flat plane I could easily obtain the position data of the 4 corner vertices. From there, I could interpolate to a 3D point in space that matches any known pixel location. But, that is UVW mapping and gets more complicated for non-square, non-flat things. Since Blender is already doing that hard work, I'd like to piggy-back.

Any ideas of where to start?

Cheers.

Comment: Sample UV Surface does that and there is a way to set camera track to constraint via geometry nodes attributes. Or you are looking for Python script solution? Please give an example of what exactly your process is.

Comment: Thank you, I will play with Sample UV Surface. But, yes, really I'm looking for a Python solution. The exact situation is an open 3D book on a table in a Blender scene. I'd like  to scan the camera across the AI identified points of interest in the images where they are mapped onto the pages. This is a pretty simple case, so I can get away with the hack described above if I need to.

Comment: In that case you can use Sample UV Surface - set up Geo Node Modifier on a vertex to land on a point of interest on the book where the specific UV coordinate is and track it's location with a Camera. For the latter I recommend watching Erindale's explainer video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4BTgkdHd30

Comment: There is a thread in Blenderartists discussing the problem with Python script solution. It is not working straight away for the current Blender version (3.6), but can be fixed with a few changes. Here is the thread: https://blenderartists.org/t/get-3d-location-of-mesh-surface-point-from-uv-parameter/649486/9 Let me know if you need help with any of the above approaches.

Comment: Thanks again. In the end I've gone with the scaling method I described above for simplicity. If I later need to track items while the pages turn and deform I will try again with the links you provided!

Comment: I am glad it works. If you need assistance with Python solution I am sure they will update it to new version if requested. Or get back here to solve it together.